# Purpose of having good credit when you are well-off?

Tags: credit-card, credit, credit-history

I notice people talk about credit scores for many things, but typically they are:

1. Helping tools for mortgages;
2. Ability to get better loans;
3. Ability to get better financing options.
4. The general reasons that apply to anyone (i.e., borrow money, get rewards, payback, etc.)

My questions are simple and mean no offense:

If you are well-off financially there's a good chance you may omit one or more of these options. For example, someone well-off can afford to simply buy a house and credit wouldn't matter specifically for this anyways. Financing vehicles may be something a person of any income or net worth could do, but if you're well-off, I don't see why this person wouldn't buy at some point even if they lease and credit can get better deals. It just seems that these tools associated with credit seem more marketed to people with lower-incomes because financing is a way of paying longer-term, which people of lower incomes may be more forced to do since they may have not enough income or overall net worth.

Also, they are probably less likely to get loans if they have a good handle on money.

By "*well-off*" I clearly don't mean rich (as in multi-millionaire or up) - I just mean someone who can afford a house/car/etc. without having to forcibly do so through long-term payments.

I'm not saying credit isn't used when you have high income, but these specifics associated with credit that are boasted about much are way less considered when you have higher net worth - hence, credit cards still have good use for any income bracket, but other things are not so much.

My dad, for example, bought the house I grew up in all straight - no mortgage/etc. He had to work years and years to comfortably do this, but nevertheless his credit didn't matter for this.

Comment: I think if you're well-off, and reasonably sensible about money, you get a good credit score whether you want it or not :-)  A mortgage is the only loan I've had since I paid off my student loans a couple of decades ago, I use credit cards for convenience (and the rewards & 0% interest - free money's always nice :-)) and always pay the balance in full, and yet somehow I wind up with an 800+ credit score.

Comment: I'm retired, saved a lot, and have no need to use credit, So I didn't and that turned out to be a big mistake because if you never use credit - which is not the same as having debt - you will have a blank credit report no matter how much you have in the bank. And this can have adverse consequences in several ways from getting cell phone service to renting apartments to booking hotel rooms. Been there done that.

Comment: If you measure being well-off by being able to buy a house outright then there would be many places where almost no one who owns a house is well-off! For example, consider Sydney, where median incomes are [$67,600](http://www.housing.nsw.gov.au/centre-for-affordable-housing/for-managers-of-affordable-housing/household-median-incomes-2016-17) and median house prices are [$1,068,303](http://www.domain.com.au/news/strongest-sydney-house-price-growth-in-a-year-domain-group-20161026-gsanr8/).

Comment: At the very least are you sure you will be well off forever? God forbid, but maybe tomorrow there will be some emergency that will heavily strain you financially. When you come out the other side of it (or perhaps even going through it) a good credit score is useful

Comment: If you have never used credit you may not have a credit rating at all.  This might be seen as highly suspicious when your rating is checked for some reason.

Comment: @doug I agree. I couldn't get a monthly cell phone contract once for a similar reason. but I see you already posted that in an answer, so you can delete your comments IMHO. DavidGrinberg your comment also makes a good answer IMHO

Comment: The paradox of credit score: The more likely you are to need credit, the less likely you are to get it.

Comment: I used to be well-off and then the company I worked for fell into insolvency. I had chosen to stick with it and help it get up again (as it did before), so I invested 6 months of my time. Now, 6 months of living expenses is surprisingly huge amount of money. I've used up all my savings and then had to borrow some. Thanks to my good credit score from better times, all I had to do was to agree to one of the offers my bank kept spamming me with. Bottom line: you might never need a good credit score, but it's better to have one when you do.

Comment: Why would you pay for a house yourself (and forgo the 5-8% interest you could get for that money on the markets) when you could just borrow the money at 2%?

Comment: I take issue with the concept that someone who can afford to pay cash for a house is not rich.  If you are born into a first world country you are automatically rich by comparison to the majority of the world.  If you have an average wage and/or a car you are exceedingly rich.  How many people could afford to travel 100km for a day trip 100 years ago?

Comment: @Stephen: rich and poor is relative, otherwise they have no meaning.

Comment: Exactly.  If you have an average household income in the US ($51000 with 2 adults and 2 children), you are in the richest 8% worldwide and have an income 14 times the average income worldwide.

Comment: @jamesqf is mostly right but there's a big exception.  Once you don't need new credit, it makes a lot of sense to turn your credit rating into cash or travel rewards by opening new credit accounts.  Since you don't really care what the rating is, it's easy and sensible to drive it down by opening accounts.  (OTOH, you're usually driving it down from "crazy high" to "reasonable.")

Comment: @James Moore: Sure, when they offer 0% interest for a year or more, or actual money for opening an account - well, as I said, free money's always nice.  Which is why I have about 8-10 credit cards,  all but two opened in the last 5 years or so, since they started those bonus offers.  (Or at least since I found out about them.)  Even so, I don't think my CR dipped much below 800.

Comment: Defintely worth keeping your credit rating up by using credit cards and paying them off in full every statement. I was recently able to change job and buy a new house out of savings and low-cost finance (including 0% card deals), without first having sold my existing residence. Hugely more satisfactory than moving into rented accomodation for a year!

Comment: "My dad, for example, bought the house I grew up in all straight - no mortgage/etc. He had to work years and years to comfortably do this, but nevertheless his credit didn't matter for this." He might have had the house a few years earlier if he would have accepted a bit of debt, like say up to 50% of the house value. Alternatively he could have had a bigger house if accepting a bit more debt. But It's also fine like he did it.

Answer (score 38):

Your dad may have paid an "opportunity cost" for that outright purchase.  If the money he saved had been invested elsewhere, he may have made more money.  If he was that well off, then his interest rate should have been the lowest possible.  My own father is a multi-millionaire (not myself) and he could afford to have paid for his house outright.  He didn't though.  To do so would have meant cashing in on several investments.  I don't know his interest rate but let's say it was 2.5%.  If he invests that million dollars into something he expects to get a 7% return on in the same period, then he would make more money by borrowing the money.  Hence, he would be paying an opportunity cost.

Assuming you need to work, some jobs will also do background or credit checks.  Credit cards can be used by well off people to actually make them money by offering rewards (compared to straight cash transactions).  The better your credit history, the better the cards/rewards you can get.  You can build that credit history better by having these loans and making timely payments.

Comment: This is true from the perspective of many "well off" people I know. Also, their tastes are more expensive - fast cars and expensive houses - which doesn't help either.

Comment: @Coomie: Not universally true.  There are a good many people (I'm one) who are well off precisely because we don't have expensive tastes, and so have invested the money we otherwise would have spent on indulging them :-)

Comment: @Coomie Expensive taste is getting a crappy credit at phone company to buy a newest iPhone you can't afford. Things you can afford are never expensive (relatively).

Comment: A similar line of thought to your father example. If I could afford a house outright, I'd still take a mortgage and buy a bigger and more central one because I'll enjoy it more and I anticipate it's a good investment despite the cost of renting that capital. Even when you have money, being able to act like you have more can be beneficial.

Comment: @Coomie I can tell that you have never read *The Millionaire Next Door*.

Comment: This is a good answer but i think there's another aspect that people tend to ignore; likely because it goes against people's sense of morality.  If you buy a house with a mortgage and the value were to drop precipitously, you can walk away.  If you buy a house with cash and it's value decreases, you lose your money.  In fact it's less risky to buy a house with debt than it is to purchase it with your capital.

Comment: @JimmyJames I don't think it's morality - I think that most people consider a house as unlikely or impossible to decrease in value.

Comment: @stannius I would have agreed with that prior to 2008 but in 2016? I'd hate to think that 'most' people have that short of a memory.  From a lot of the blah blah blah on this site, it seems like a lot of people are actually irrationally worried about that happening now.  I don't even mean a huge housing bubble type problem.  I recently read about a guy who discovered his driveway is paved with radioactive waste.  He'd be better off letting the bank deal with it.

Comment: Unfortunately for that guy, radioactive waste is his problem unless he can prove that it is someone else's.

Comment: This applies in business in general - it was even main theme of lessons of economics on my uni.

Comment: @Agent_L: An iPhone (and contract) is expensive even if you can afford it, if everything you want a phone to do can be done by a $25 dumb phone and a $7/month PAYG carrier.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling is that an interesting read?

Comment: @NuWin It is a little dated in details, but if you want to read about actual millionaires rather than stereotypes, it's definitely worth a look.

Comment: "Opportunity cost?" Making a *lot* of assumptions there. Just to name a handful of the top of my head 1. The alternative investment made money instead of losing it 2. it made *enough* money to beat the spread on the loan(s) 3. the OP has sufficient risk tolerance for this shell game 4. the OP is interested in maintaining it, etc, etc.

Comment: Of course if you really can make a steady 7% profit and can borrow at 2.5% then you should take the biggest possible loan and use that as a lever and get even richer. However I doubt such a ratio is possible in the long run. It's probably better to directly invest into yourself - this way at least the banks as middlemen are cut out.

Comment: @stannius "radioactive waste is his problem unless he can prove that it is someone else's".  If he owed on a mortgage, he could just stop making payments and leave.  Then the bank will take ownership.  That's the whole point I'm making here.

Comment: @Trilarion This oversimplifies things. First, a home is an  illiquid asset. Unless you have a large plot, you really can't convert part of it to cash in a pinch. Secondly, in the US at least, all your interest payments are tax deductible. With that and low interest rates (like now) it's easy to lock in a long-term rate below what the market as a whole returns. Third, a house is inherently non-diversified. Forth, returns on the home are not improved by owning it outright. If it goes up 100K, you get 100K regardless of whether you have a mortgage. If it goes down, you can walk away.

Comment: @JimmyJames You can't just abandon contamination like radiation and oil leaks. As far as I understand it, if you are the owner at time of discovery, you are on the hook for the cost of the environmental cleanup, even if you attempt to sell or abandon the property. Even proving it was there before you bought the house doesn't help - you have to prove who is responsible, and if you don't, de facto you are responsible. That said, if it's something more simple like flooding/mold or even just dropping in price due to the market, then yes you might be able to walk away.

Comment: @stannius I can't argue the details but he can still stop making payments and move away.  In the case I am referring to it was already documented by the EPA prior to the purchase.

Comment: @stannius I don't have time to parse all the legalese but as of 2002, there are [liability protections for "innocent landowners"](https://www.epa.gov/enforcement/landowner-liability-protections).  I was able to find that CERCLA § 101(35)(A)(i) recognizes purchasers who acquire property without knowledge of the contamination.

Comment: @JimmyJames ... dropping a mortgage when the house looses value is only ever profitable for you if (i) The real estate crashes (i.e. not a small dip), and (ii) You didn't put a large initial deposit and you're only at the very beginning of your payments (=you haven't already sinked more money in the mortgage than the house lost value). So keeping this option as a strategic choice only covers you for a very specific set of circumstances, and for a relatively short time (compared to a typical mortgage duration) ... not what I would call a "managed" risk.

Comment: @Hoki You seem to be agreeing on all the points.  A typical mortgage in the US is 30 years.  It generally takes something like 10 years to pay as much on the mortgage as you would if you buy with cash.  That's not really a 'short time'.  It's a full third of the mortgage duration.  And much beyond that, you are mostly paying principle anyway.

Comment: @JimmyJames it should be noted that in many countries the prevailing practice is that if you walk away from mortgage *you still owe the bank* the difference between your current remaining debt and whatever they could get for the house. Which might be mighty little in case of the radiation cleanup.

Answer (score 28):

Credit scores, or at least components of them, can sometimes factor into how much you pay for car insurance.

Source: [Consumer Reports: How a Credit Score Increases your Premium](http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/car-insurance/credit-scores-affect-auto-insurance-rates/index.htm)

Comment: This is true in most states. I'm lucky (because I used to have zero credit) to be in Calif. where insurance companies are not allowed to use credit reports for auto insurance.

Comment: At this level of wealth, self-insurance can be an option.

Comment: @MSalters some jurisdictions (such as Great Britain) do not allow self-insurance for cars

Comment: @Qsigma: Does the UK have universal credit scores? The question only makes sense in a few jurisdictions anyway.

Comment: Many US states have mandatory insurance, however the required amount is usually fairly minimal, so paying more for it shouldn't hurt the hypothetical rich person.

Comment: @stannius Unfortunately, mandatory (legal minimum) insurance coverage generally doesn't protect you that much.

Comment: @MSalters The UK has 3rd party credit scores, if that is what you mean. I don't know if the UK is like California, and omits credit reports from premium calculations. I agree with you that self-insurance can be an option, _if_ the jurisdiction permits it, and _if_ our hypothetical well off person still has substantial liquid assets _after_ they have bought the house

Comment: @MSalters UK also has sensible insurance, unlike USA. You can volunteer to pay the first £xxx of every claim (to keep insurer's admin overheads lower for not covering tiny mishaps), but by law the upper payout limit is *unlimited*. Insurance companies can reinsure multimillion pound risks of extreme low probabliity. Nobody's financial wellbeing can get trashed by an accident with extreme consequences, short of bankrupting a re-insurer.

Comment: One risk to self-insurance is having that cash tied up. My recollection is that to be self-insured you have to put the state-mandated minimum insurance coverage on deposit with the state. That money is tied up, not earning interest, and not available for other purposes.

Answer (score 26):

Because even if you won the lottery, without at least some credit history you will have trouble renting cars and hotel rooms.

I learned about the importance, and limitations of credit history when, in the 90's, I switched from using credit cards to doing everything with a debit card and checks purely for convenience. Eventually, my unused credit cards were not renewed. At that point in my life I had saved a lot and had high liquidity. I even bought new autos every 5 years with cash.

Then, last decade, I found it increasingly hard to rent cars and sometimes even a hotel rooms with a debit card even though I would say they could precharge whatever they thought necessary to cover any expenses I might run.

I started investigating why and found out that hotels and car rentals saw having a credit card as a proxy for low risk that you would damage the car or hotel room and not pay.

So then I researched credit cards, credit reports, and how they worked. They have nothing about any savings, investments, or bank accounts you have. I had no idea this was the case. And, since I hadn't had cards or bought anything on credit in over 10 years there were no records in my credit files. Old, closed accounts had fallen off after 10 years.

So, I opened a couple of secured credit cards with the highest security deposit allowed. They unsecured after a year or so. Then, I added several rewards cards. I use them instead of a debit card and always pay in full and they provide some cash back so I save money compared to just using a debit card. After 4 years my credit score has gone to 800+ even though I have never carried any debt and use the cards as if they were debit cards. I was very foolish to have stopped using credit cards 20 years ago but just had no idea of the importance of an established credit history. And note that establishing a great credit history does not require that you borrow money or take out loans for anything. just get credit cards and pay them in full each month.

Comment: This is arguing for a credit _card_, not a credit _score_. For the well-off who are the subject of this question, a good credit score is just a side effect of using a credit card.

Comment: MSalters I don't understand your comment. If your credit card provider uses credit scoring (as I think most do), you need a good score to get a mainstream card with no fees.

Comment: Credit cards are the largest, positive factor in a credit score and, unlike other reported debts like auto loans or mortgages, they can have zero cost and even save money. If you only get a credit card, pay it on time, and have no negatives in your credit file, you will have good credit.

Comment: The rental cars & hotel rooms argument is irrelevant if your lifestyle is such that you don't rent cars or stay in hotels.  OTOH, having a credit card makes it a good bit easier to buy stuff & pay bills online.

Comment: "Because even if you won the lottery, without at least some credit history you will have trouble renting cars and hotel rooms." I would rather say payment history since even with credit cards you can operate them in a way that you never take any credit. And if you won the lottery, you will automatically get a good payment history. What you argue for is more the necessity of having a credit card. It also depends on the location. I live in Europe, and can rent cars or pay for hotel rooms well even before I had a credit card (now I have one, but I never use the credit).

Comment: @Trilarion I can't speak to Europe, but in the US many car rentals require a credit card to rent an auto. Also, "winning the lottery" likely would provide the means to pay but many people with the means do not timely pay their bills and so have bad credit. There is nothing automatic about having good credit no matter how much money you have. If you consistently pay your credit card late it will likely be canceled because your credit reports have no information about assets you have or don't have so you will be considered high risk.

Answer (score 21):

A $250K earner might have $4M in retirement savings and $500K in available funds, but doesn't wish to spend all his liquidity on the house. In general, a house might cost 2-3 times one's annual income. It would take many years to get that saved up. They might want to have the house sooner.

It all goes back to choice, priorities, personal preference.

Comment: That's a good point. A mortgage is hard to get if you have not established a credit history. Too many avoid credit cards because they see them in a negative light and associate them with debt which they eschew. But credit cards can be used like debit cards where you pay in full. Not only are they cost free but you can get rewards and cash back as well. Doing  so for just 3 or 4 years will make it easy to get a mortgage at the best rates and save tens of thousands of dollars.

Comment: $4M in retirement savings and still having a mortgage? I understand not sacrificing liquidity, but those retirement savings need not be liquid. Also, a paid-off house effectively is part of a retirement package.

Comment: @MSalters -  This year, that $250K earner (or any couple with access to a 401(k)) can put aside $36K into their retirement account. Add $11K into their IRAs. It's very possible that an older couple has exactly this mix, very heavily skewed toward their retirement accounts.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, the advice is that you should not buy a house that costs more than three times your annual income.  Somehow, that's gotten reversed into being a minimum rather than a limit.

Comment: @Mark - I do not understand the comment. I offer 2 to 1, not 3X. It's just an example. I tried to show that someone who is in great shape for a future retirement can still prefer to get the mortgage.

Comment: @Mark: That's basically saying the house price should be around 300% annual income. But that's not a direct concern; the portion of your income spent on housing is. There are two major drivers for house prices, interest and the wish to pay off the mortgage during your career. At the current rates, the latter term has come to dominate the equation. For instance, I expect to soon pay <1% interest, which leaves about 3% repayment. That means the 3X house price comes in at only 12% of my annual income, instead of the 30% which was common when interest was ~7%. 4X-5X today is still comparable.

Answer (score 7):

People just love becoming more well-off than they currently are, and one of the ways they do it is with [leverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_(finance)). Leverage requires credit. That desire is not exclusive to people who are not already well-off.

For a well-off person who wants to become more well-off by expanding their real estate ventures, paying cash for property is a terrible way to go about it. The same goes for other types of business or market investment. Credit benefits the well-off even more greatly than it benefits the poor or the middle-class.

Comment: Why is paying cash a terrible way to go about investing in real estate and business?

Comment: "Credit benefits the well-off even more greatly than it benefits the poor or the middle-class." Really? So they lend each other the money (after all it has to come from somewhere) and magically that makes them better off? Leverage surely goes in both directions.

Comment: @Trilarion actually the money doesn't have to come from anywhere. A bank can take, say, $10k in deposits and use that as the reserve to make a $100k loan. $90k just got created out of thin air. Here's a half-decent explanation: http://www.cnbc.com/id/100497710

Comment: Because, @tubes, with credit they can do ten times as much business as they can with cash. In other words, ten times the profit potential. Did you read the link to the WP article on leverage?

Comment: @stannius Okay, but still leverage still goes both ways. I just doubt, leverage beyond a certain level is actually making anyone more well-off. It just fuels a credit bubble which bursts at some point and in the end you might even lose money overall. As a defensive stance in certain situations it might make sense to buy some property paying cash for those who love not to be less well-off.

Answer (score 4):

Credit in general having no significant change between an income level or net worth is due to the **economic reciprocity principle** inherent in many societies. Although some areas of credit may be more admirable to those who aren't as well-off, such as car loans, the overall understanding of credit is a trust agreement between someone getting something (e.g., credit card user) and someone giving something (e.g., bank or company). Credit doesn't have to mean just money -- it can be anything of value, including tangible materials, services, etc. The fact is that a credit is a common element in most economical systems, and as such its use is not really variable between income levels/etc.

Sure, there is variance in things like credit line amounts and rewards, but the overall gist is the same for everyone -- borrowing, paying back, benefits, etc. All of these exchanges form the same understanding we all know and follow. Credit brings along with it trust -- the form represented in a score. While not everyone may depend entirely on credit, and no one should use credit as a means of getting by entirely (money), everyone can understand and reap the benefits of a system whether they make 10K a year of 10M a year. This is the general idea behind credit in the broadest sense possible.

Besides, just because one has or makes more money doesn't mean they don't prefer to get good deals. Nobody should like being taken advantage of, and if credit can help, anyone can establish trust.

Comment: Trust is maybe more closely related to the payment/transaction history (e.g. how timely one pays for his bills). It doesn't have to be credit necessarily. Even if you never took any credit in your life I think your actions can still tell me if I should trust you or not.

Answer (score 4):

I have never had a credit card and have been able to function perfectly well without one for 30 years. I borrowed money twice, once for a school loan that was countersigned, and once for my mortgage. In both cases my application was accepted.

You only need to have "good credit" if you want to borrow money.

Credit scores are usually only relevant for people with irregular income or a past history of delinquency. Assuming the debtor has no history of delinquency, the only thing the bank really cares about is the income level of the applicant.

In the old days it could be difficult to rent a car without a credit car and this was the only major problem for me before about 2010. Usually I would have to make a cash deposit of $400 or something like that before a rental agency would rent me a car. This is no longer a problem and I never get asked for a deposit anymore to rent cars.

Other than car rentals, I never had a problem not having a credit card.

Comment: As someone who has never borrowed money (in the official sense -- technically, parents have (rarely) loaned me <$20 for a day or so in the past), I can confirm that I have had no trouble because of a low (or lack thereof) credit score. When you don't borrow money, it just rarely comes up. And that includes renting and going to college. (I will graduate debt free this year with a Bachelors.)

Answer (score 2):

there are several reasons you might want good credit even if you could afford to pay for all your expenses in cash.

1. **leverage**: even if you have enough cash to buy a house, you might want to invest that cash instead. assuming your investments earn more than your mortgage interest, you come out ahead.  mortgage interest is generally much lower than other margin interst. credit card interest can be zero for people with good credit.
2. **tax breaks**: mortgage interest is tax deductible. also, investing inside retirement accounts can provide tax breaks. however retirement funds are not always available for other large purchase (e.g. house, car, yacht)
3. **rental and insurance rates**: having good credit can get you better rates on things like car insurance and life insurance, etc. also, rental companies of all sorts, from cars and hotels to construction equipment will give you better and more convenient rental terms if you have good credit.
4. **promotional offers**.  there are a lot of promotional offers available in the credit space.  notably, sign-up bonuses and/or cash back offers for credit cards can pay you hundreds of dollars per year if you have good credit.
5. **liquidity**: you may not have the funds you need on hand for various purchases (e.g. house). tax rules (regarding retirement accounts, long term capital gains, wash sales, etc.) can all limit the availability of your funds.  there are also some illiquid investments. for example, you may have real estate or collectibles that are difficult to sell for a good price on short notice.
6. **liability**:  during the recent real estate crash, many home owners chose to allow the bank to foreclose because it was cheaper than selling the house and taking a loss.  especially in states that protect borrowers from liability, mortgage default can be a very profitable option. if you are considering liquidating retirement assets to buy a house, this is particularly interesting since retirement accounts have some protections from bankruptcy (although, your primary residence has other protections too).
7. **employment opportunities**: employers are allowed to make hiring decisions based on credit scores in some states.  also, federal security clearance requires a background check that includes a credit check.  it seems unlikely that a few missed payments would make the difference in getting a job, but it is potentially a factor especially in the financial sector.

having pointed out all the above reasons to have good credit, it is probably worth noting that many people with good credit choose to not borrow simply because they are more comfortable with the risks of not borrowing (e.g. inflation risk), than they are with the risks of borrowing (e.g. investment volatility).

Comment: Very good answer although there are also quite some reasons one might not want to take any credit most prominent being maybe potential losses in case the investments earnings are less than the mortgage interest on average.

Comment: @Trilarion that is worth noting. i have updated my answer with a footnote accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Credit is very important even if you are wealthy.

One thing you may not realize is that rich people typically have comparatively little cash on hand.  If they're smart, most of their assets are not liquid - they're tied up in safe, long-term investments.  They use credit for their day-to-day expenses and pay it off from the dividends on their investments (which might only come in once a quarter).

There are also tax advantages to using credit.  If a rich person wanted a new car, he'd be smarter leasing it for his business (immediate write-off of the lease payments on taxes) versus buying it (depreciation over several years plus property tax liability in some states).  There are more elaborate tax dodges but the point is that buying a car outright is the worst option in terms of tax avoidance.

Another way the rich (mis) use credit is so that they don't risk their own money on business ventures.  Let's say I have $1,000,000 in my personal bank account, and I want to buy a business that costs $1M.  If I am dumb, I clean out my bank account and put all my money in the business.  I get 100% of the profits, but I also bear 100% of the risk.  If I'm smart, I loan 200K of my own money in the business and put the rest someplace safe, and get a loan from a bank for the other 800K.  If the business succeeds, the bank gets their money back plus interest.  If it fails, the business declares bankruptcy and the bank eats the 800k loss. If I structured the debt right, my personal loan to the failed business gets paid back first when the company is liquidated, and the bank gets whatever is left over (if anything).  The most of my own money I can possibly lose is 200k, and probably it's closer to zero if I have a good accountant.

Comment: "If I structured the debt right, my personal loan to the failed business gets paid back first when the company is liquidated, and the bank gets whatever is left over (if anything)." - Do banks really agree to such terms? I guess the idea is nice, but in practice this hardly happens.

Comment: @Trilarion No, no sane bank would provide an unsecured loan for a personal business venture.